# copy part of one dict to a new dict based on a list of keys

Tags: python, dictionary

Sample:

```
d = {
    "test": 1,
    "sample": 2,
    "example": 3,
    "product": 4,
    "software": 5,
    "demo": 6,
}

filter_keys = ["test","sample","example","demo"]
```

I want to create a new dict that contains only those items from the first dict whose keys appear in the list. In other words, I want:

```
d2 = {
    "test": 1,
    "sample": 2,
    "example": 3,
    "demo": 6,
}
```

I could do it with a loop:

```
d2 = {}
for k in d.keys():
    if (k in filter_keys): 
        d2[k] = d[k]
```

But this seems awfully "un-Pythonic". I'm also guessing that if you had a huge dict, say 5,000 items or so, the constant adding of new items to the new dict would be slow compared to a more direct way.

Also, you'd want to be able to handle errors. If the list contains something that's not a key in the dict, it should just be ignored. Or maybe it gets added to the new dict but with a value of None.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: You have asked many questions without accepting answers for those questions. You should accept answers.

Answer (score 5):

A straight-forward way to do this is with the "dictionary comprehension":

```
filtered_dict = {key: value for key, value in d.items() if key in filter_keys}
```

Note that if the condition appears at the end of the comprehension, it filters execution of the loop statement. Depending on whether the numbers of keys in the dictionary is greater than the number of keys you want to filter on, this revision could be more efficient:

```
filtered_dict = {key: d[key] for key in filter_keysif key in d}
```

Checking for membership in the dictionary (`key in d`) is significantly faster than checking for membership in the filter key list (`key in filter_keys`). But which ends up faster depends on the size of the filter key list (and, to a lesser extent, the size of the dictionary).

A relatively python way to do it without a dictionary comprehension is with the `dict` constructor:

```
filtered_dict = dict([(key, value) for key, value in d.items() if key in filter_keys])
```

Note that this is essentially equivalent to the dictionary comprehension, but may be clearer if you aren't familiar with dictionary comprehension syntax.

Comment: No need to build a list to pass to the dict constructor -- a generator expression will do just fine.

Comment: Awesome on the dictionary comprehension. I use list comprehensions all the time but never knew you could do the same with a dict.

Comment: @fdmillion -- Yep, they were added in python2.7 along with set comprehensions, e.g:  `{x*x for x in something}`

Comment: Yes, the list is not necessary. You could write `dict((key, value) for key, value in d.items() if key in l)`, which would be passing a generator into the `dict` constructor. In this case, they are likely to be about the same speed.

Answer (score 1):

For optimal performance, you should iterate over the keys in the list and check if they are in the dict rather than the other way around:

```
d2 = {}
for k in list_of_keys:
    if k in d:
       d2[k] = d[k]
```

The benefit here is that the `dict.__contains__` (`in`) on a `dict` is O(1) whereas for the list it's O(N).  For big lists, that's a HUGE benefit (O(N) algorithm vs. O(N^2)).

We can be a little more succinct by expressing the above loop with an equivalent dict-comprehension:

```
d2 = {k: d[k] for k in list_of_keys if k in d}
```

This will be likely be marginally faster than the loop, but probably not enough to ever worry about.  That said, most python programmers would prefer this version as it is more succinct and very common.

Comment: @EML, think about the logic, why iterate over the full dict instead of just the four list items?

Comment: Sorry I removed my comment - I intended to edit it. Whether or not this is more efficient depends on whether the keys we intend to filter on are actually a subset of the keys in the dictionary. The filter list could be larger than the number of keys actually in the dictionary. Of course, there is significant savings in checking a dictionary for membership rather than a list, so I edited my comment to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary comprehension is one way to do it:

```
new_d = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if k in l}
```

Demo:

```
>>> d = {
...     "test": 1,
...     "sample": 2,
...     "example": 3,
...     "product": 4,
...     "software": 5,
...     "demo": 6,
... }
>>>
>>> l = ["test","sample","example","demo"]
>>> new_d = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if k in l}
>>> new_d
{'sample': 2, 'demo': 6, 'test': 1, 'example': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your last part of the question:

*Or maybe it gets added to the new dict but with a value of None.*

```
l = ["test","sample","example","demo","badkey"]
d = {
    "test": 1,
    "sample": 2,
    "example": 3,
    "product": 4,
    "software": 5,
    "demo": 6,
}


print {k: d.get(k) for k in l}
{'test': 1, 'sample': 2, 'badkey': None, 'example': 3, 'demo': 6}
```

You can pass a default return value to `dict.get`, it is `None` by default but you could set it to `d.get(k,"No_match")` etc.. or whatever value you wanted.